# Error while autocomplete a country dropdown because its countryCode is undefined

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have an input box for country list , I want to fill it's value with countryCode which is like  `billingAddressForm.controls.country.value?.countryCode` when its being autocompleted then the value is not an object containing `name` and `countryCode` and its the auto-completed value , for example `"Germany"` and not `{name: Germany , countryCode: "DE"}`

I want to check and if its countryCode is undefined and then show an error and don't let the form save , or open the country dropdown to select from list and set countryCode

```
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries | async" [value]="country"> {{ country.countryCode }}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
<mat-error
*ngIf="billingAddressForm.controls.country.hasError('required')"
>
  {{ 'error' }}
</mat-error>
```